# Detecting multivariate outliers in multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, outliers

I am running a multiple regression and wish to screen for outliers. I have the variables Y (outcome), and predictors X1, X2, X3.

For univariate outliers, I can check each variable for z-scored values > 3.29 (Tabachnick & Fidell, 2007). Alternatively a more robust method would be to calculate the median absolute deviation and check for cases with where the value is greater than the median +/- 2.5 * median absolute deviation (Leys et al ., 2013).

For multivariate outliers, I can use Mahalonobis Distance. When calculating the Mahalonobis Distance, should I calculate it with all variables (i.e. Y, X1, X2, X3) or only the predictor variables (X1, X2, X3)?

Tabachnick & Fidell (2007): https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2006-03883-000
Leys et al.(2013):  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022103113000668?via%3Dihub